# How to style the edit-icons in the Tinymce editor like buttons?

Tags: button, tinymce, styles

In the TinyMCE - Full featured example (http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/full.php) the edit-buttons of the editor really look like buttons, they have this border around each button-group, fe around the b,u and s-buttons. 
In my implementation there are no borders around the icons. I went over these icons with firebug, but didnt get behind whats making these borders.
Can someone tell me, how i can use this button-look within my implementation?

Thanks, Schmitty

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the full featured example page have a look at "View Source".
The you will find the following lines you should try as your init

```
tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

        // Skin options
        skin : "o2k7",
        skin_variant : "silver",

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css : "css/example.css",

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "js/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "js/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "js/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "js/media_list.js",

        // Replace values for the template plugin
        template_replace_values : {
                username : "Some User",
                staffid : "991234"
        }
});
```

Comment: if an answer solves your problem i suggest you accept that answer (+ maybe add an upvote)

Comment: I would like to, but am not allowed to as not registered user. Maybe i gonna register, so i can upvote good answers like yours.

Comment: aah, didn't know you were able to ask questions without being registerd